# Как сделать ЛОГИН в laravel на два поля

Tags: php, laravel, auth

по стандарту в laravel  одно поля для username при в ходе в аккаунт. Вот например сейчас у меня на сайте стоит вход по полю `number` а как сделать чтобы вход был по двум полям это `number` и `ik`. На сайте при входе два поля **(номер телефона и пароль)** нужно чтобы в номер телефона можно было вписать не только сам номер для входа но и индивидуальный ключ(это уже другое поле в бд ) и вход в аккаунт был успешный. Если так нельзя сделать то предложите альтернативный вариант входа по  двум полям

Comment: Можно принимать 2 поля и склеивать их, потом проводить вход... Тут даже можно фронтом обойтись

Answer (score 1):

В файле **LoginController.php** переопределите метод username по какому полю осуществлять вход. Небольшой пример по входу email и name

```
public function username(): string
{
   $login = request()->input('email');
   $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'name';
   request()->merge([$field => $login]);
   return $field;
}
```